# Line separator in css

Tags: html, css

HTML code snippet:

```
<div id="post_nav">
    <a class="prev" href="/2014/11/28/markdown-and-html.html">Some title <br/>Prev</a>
    <a class="next" href="/2014/11/30/sample-post.html">Some title <br/>Next</a>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
#post_nav {
  width:100%;
  display: inline-block;
  border-bottom: 1px solid $border-color;
}
#post_nav .prev {
  padding: 3% 5% 3% 10%;
  @media (max-width: 1000px) {
    padding: 3% 10%;
  }
  width: 50%;
  display: inline-block;
  float: left;
  text-align: left;
}
#post_nav .next {
  padding: 3% 5% 3% 10%;
  @media (max-width: 1000px) {
    padding: 3% 10%;
  }
  width: 50%;
  display: inline-block;
  text-align: right;
  border-left: 1px solid rgba(0,0,0,0.1);
}
```

Problem:

It works fine but when left link text is longer than the right link text, the border/line-separator isn't complete. See below snap shot:

[image]

How can I resolve this?

Comment: create a demo with relevant code?

Comment: Your code looks like : http://jsfiddle.net/qbky1ak6/1/

Comment: You have an `@media` at-rule inside another ruleset - AFAIK that's not valid, it may screw up your tests.

Comment: @ketan Try to increase length of the left link text, the separator won't be complete.

Comment: @AntaraRoy Yes that is because you give `border-left` to `#post_nav .next` so if `.prev` height increase it won't complete.

Comment: @AntaraRoy Check http://jsfiddle.net/qbky1ak6/2/

Comment: @ketan Thanks for the answer but when the `next` link is absent I want the `prev` link not to take the entire space, can i achieve that?

Comment: @AntaraRoy something like? http://jsfiddle.net/qbky1ak6/3/

Comment: @ketan I want like this - http://i.imgur.com/sG2Mjbt.png

Comment: @AntaraRoy For that you should use `display:flex`. http://jsfiddle.net/qbky1ak6/5/

Comment: @ketan yes this was what i wanted, please post as answer to this question.

Comment: @AntaraRoy i can't answer because this question is closed.